# How to make a equation have a label at the last equation using \begin{split}

Tags: equations, split

How to make the label of equation at the end of the equation?

and not in the middle of equation using `\begin{split}`

[image]

My MWE:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
A =& A+ B \\
  =& A-C \\
  =& d + f -d \\
  =& 1234
\end{split}
\end{equation}


\begin{equation}
A =  1234
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Off-topic: In order to get the typographically correct amount of spacing around the `=` symbols, it's *essential* to write `&=` rather than `=&`.

Comment: @Mico. Thanks.It is strange that both way `=&` and `&=` works. But i guess `&=` is better. But I could not see the difference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the environment `DispWithArrows` of `witharrows` (which is similar to `align` of `amsmath`), you have an option to specify that you want to tag only the last line.

You may also fix globally this option with `\WithArrowsOptions{tagged-lines = last}`.

Of course, the first aim of `witharrows` is to add arrows in such alignments and that's why I've added an arrow.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{witharrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{DispWithArrows}[tagged-lines = last]
A & = A+ B \\
  & = A-C \Arrow{an arrow} \\
  & = d + f -d \\
  & = 1234
\end{DispWithArrows}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result of the above code]

Comment: Thanks. What happened if I want to specific a line to be label (either line 2, line 3). I posted another questions.

Comment: Take a closer look at the space around the `=` signs.  The `&` should precede it: `&=`.

Comment: @ Babara Beeton: You re right. I have modified.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

If this features is desired in whole document, than the asmath's option `tbtags` solve your problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[tbtags]{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
A & = A+ B      \\
  & = A-C       \\
  & = d + f -d  \\
  & = 1234
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
A =  1234
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Zarco ... see the second comment in my answer ... (+1)

Comment: +1. Do please change all instances of `= &` to `&=`, though.

Comment: @Zarko, Thanks. What happened if I want to specific a line to be label (either line 2, line 3). I posted another questions. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/542050/how-can-i-specify-which-line-of-the-equation-i-want-to-label-it

Comment: @Mico, you are right. I (again) overlooked this misplacing in OP question. Corrected!

Comment: @aan, I clearly stated that use of `tbtag` influence on all similar cases in document. If you like to change placement in just one occasions, than you should stick with other answers.

Answer (score 4):

Try like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,draft]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}


\begin{document}



\begin{align}\nonumber
A &= A+ B \\\nonumber
  &= A-C \\\nonumber
  &= d + f -d \\
  &= 1234
\end{align}



\begin{equation}
A =  1234
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Generally, you should stack two separate align/equation environments like that.  It'd be better to include the equation into the align (and I'd probably have `\nonumber` just before `\\ `, since that's the line it's modifying).

Comment: With `=&` in the `align`, we don't have the right space after the `=`. You should use `&=` instead.

Comment: @Teepeemm It is just an example I suppose and I can't know if one align could be ok for the op ... He could possibly have already used one and not two, bat mau be you are right... About the `\nonumber` LaTeX doesn't really care if it is before or after the equation ...

Comment: @F.Pantigny ... Yes ... right ... just copy pasted and didn't try to improve the code ... just added the code in a `align` environment and could nor right all that in a comment (it shows terrible ...) [Thanks ... fixed!]

Comment: `\notag` is equivalent to `\nonumber`, and is shorter to type.