# How can I specify which line of the equation I want to label it?

Tags: equations

This is a following up question for [How to make an equation label at the last](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/542026/how-to-make-a-equation-have-a-lable-at-the-last-equation-using-beginsplit/542042#542042)

How about if I want to specify which line of the equation I want to label it?
To label at the end of equation, the solution can be found in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/542026/how-to-make-a-equation-have-a-lable-at-the-last-equation-using-beginsplit/542042#542042).

[image]

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
A =& A+ B \\
  =& A-C \\   %label here OR label the last 2 line
  =& d + f -d \\
  =& d + r+ f+ f \\
  =& f + r + e +f \\ %label here
  =& 1234
\end{split}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: You should place the `&` in front of the equals sign not after it to get the correct spacing. This is true for all binary operators or relations in `align`, `split`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `align` and suppress line numbering using `\nonumber`:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[]{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
A &= A+ B \nonumber\\
  &= A-C \\   %label here OR label the last 2 line
  &= d + f -d \nonumber\\
  &= d + r+ f+ f \nonumber\\
  &= f + r + e +f \\ %label here
  &= 1234 \nonumber
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Note that you get the correct spacing if you place the `&` before the equals sign.

Results with both lines numbered (you can remove one of the numbers by placing an additional `\nonumber`):

[image]

Comment: Or `\notag` – this saves typing two letters.

Comment: Sorry for the typo. I meant \notag, of course.

Comment: @Bernard Yes, but I find `\nonumber` easier to remember :)

Comment: Perhaps because you rarely use  `\newtagform` and `\usetagform`?

Comment: @Bernard why should I? :)

Comment: You shouldn't particularly, but it helps me remembering.

Comment: @Bernard -- Three letters.  (Sorry, inveterate nitpicker.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton: I'm  sorry, I counted on my fingers –  still have only have five per hand, and I forgot to carry above  5 ;–)

Comment: @Bernard -- I suspected it might be something like that.  Are you a mathematician?  I have observed that pure mathematicians are often somewhat weak on arithmetic; but what they are really good at, I can only marvel at.  (grin.)

Comment: Yes, I am (commutative algebra, so quite pure…). Actually, not so weak, but very easily absent-minded.

Answer (score 1):

With the environment `{DispWithArrows}` of the package `witharrows`, which is similar to the environment `{align}` of `amsmath`, we can specify the list of the lines you want to tag with the option `tagged-lines`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{witharrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{DispWithArrows}[tagged-lines={2,4}]
A &= A+ B \\
  &= A-C \\ 
  &= d + f -d \\
  &= d + r+ f+ f \\
  &= f + r + e +f \\ 
  &= 1234 
\end{DispWithArrows}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result of the above code]