# Equation sublabeling

Tags: equations, counters, cases

Code:

```
%\documentclass[12 pt,handout,notheorems]{beamer}
\documentclass[12 pt,handout,notheorems, serif]{beamer}
%\documentclass[12 pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{resize to}[a4paper,landscape]
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts} %To get the accents aligned correctly, albeit in Computer Modern Roman
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mleftright}
\mleftright
\begin{document}
    \setcounter{equation}{14}
    \begin{equation}
        F = ma
    \end{equation}
    \begin{equation}
        \delta\left(t\right)= 
        \begin{cases}
            \infty & t = 0,\\
            0 & t \neq 0.
        \end{cases}
    \end{equation}
    \begin{equation}
        u\left(t\right)= 
        \begin{cases}
            1 & t \geq 0,\\
            0 & t < 0.
        \end{cases}
    \end{equation}
    \begin{equation}
        v = \omega r
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

Is there a way to relabel equation 16 as 16a and 16b for the top and bottom equations in `cases`, as well as 17 to 17a and 17b?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `subnumcases` defined in the `cases` package:

```
\documentclass[12 pt,handout,notheorems, serif]{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts} 

\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \setcounter{equation}{14}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{equation}
        F = ma
    \end{equation}   
\begin{subnumcases}{\delta(t) = }
\infty  & $t = 0$,    \\
     0  & $t \neq 0$.
\end{subnumcases}
\begin{subnumcases}{u(t)=}
    1   & $t \geq 0$,   \\
    0   & $t < 0$.
\end{subnumcases}
    \begin{equation}
        v = \omega r
    \end{equation}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is a trick I learned from [this nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/542042/194703) by the author of the `witharrows` package, which has a lot of hidden gems I did not appreciate enough before.

The point is that you can use `witharrows` even without arrows.

```
\documentclass[12 pt,handout,notheorems, serif]{beamer}
%\documentclass[12 pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{resize to}[a4paper,landscape]
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts} %To get the accents aligned correctly, albeit in Computer Modern Roman
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mleftright}
\usepackage{witharrows}
\renewcommand{\left}{\mleft}%<- seriously?
\renewcommand{\right}{\mright}%<- seriously?
\begin{document}
    \setcounter{equation}{14}
    \begin{equation}
        F = ma
    \end{equation}
    \begin{subequations}
    \begin{DispWithArrows}< \delta\left(t\right)= >
            \infty\;,\quad & t = 0\;,\\
            0\;,\quad & t \neq 0\;.
    \end{DispWithArrows}
    \end{subequations}
    \begin{subequations}
    \begin{DispWithArrows}< u\left(t\right)= >
            1\;,\quad  & t \geq 0\;,\\
            0\;,\quad  & t < 0\;.
    \end{DispWithArrows}
    \end{subequations}
    \begin{equation}
        v = \omega r
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or with left aligned columns and `\mleftright` as suggested by Mico.

```
\documentclass[12 pt,handout,notheorems, serif]{beamer}
%\documentclass[12 pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{resize to}[a4paper,landscape]
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts} %To get the accents aligned correctly, albeit in Computer Modern Roman
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mleftright}
\usepackage{witharrows}
\mleftright
% \renewcommand{\left}{\mleft}%<- seriously?
% \renewcommand{\right}{\mright}%<- seriously?
\begin{document}
    \setcounter{equation}{14}
    \begin{equation}
        F = ma
    \end{equation}
    \begin{subequations}
    \begin{DispWithArrows}< \delta\left(t\right)= >
            \infty\;,\quad & t = 0\;,\\
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\myw}{width("$\infty$")}\makebox[\myw pt][l]{$0$}\;,\quad & t \neq 0\;.
    \end{DispWithArrows}
    \end{subequations}
    \begin{subequations}
    \begin{DispWithArrows}< u\left(t\right)= >
            1\;,\quad  & t \geq 0\;,\\
            0\;,\quad  & t < 0\;.
    \end{DispWithArrows}
    \end{subequations}
    \begin{equation}
        v = \omega r
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hmmm what does `< \delta\left(t\right)= >` do?

Comment: @Superman As far as I understand this the stuff between `<` and `>` will be left of the brace.

Answer (score 3):

Just for the sake of variety, here's a solution which uses the `cases` package and its `subnumcases` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,handout,notheorems, serif]{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{resize to}[a4paper,landscape]
\usepackage{cases} % for 'subnumcases' environment
% 'amsmath' is loaded automatically by 'beamer' class
\begin{document}
\setcounter{equation}{14}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{equation}
        F = ma
    \end{equation}
    \begin{subnumcases}{\delta(t)=}
        \infty & $t = 0$,\\
        0      & $t \neq 0$.
    \end{subnumcases}
    \begin{subnumcases}{u(t)=}
        1 & $t \geq 0$,\\
        0 & $t < 0$.
    \end{subnumcases}
    \begin{equation}
        v = \omega r
    \end{equation}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: All three are pretty good answers! Thank you so much @all

Comment: @Superman - Please "accept" Zarko's answer -- he posted his solution a few minutes before I posted mine.